# how to build voro++ in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, voronoi

I have downloaded the last version on voro++, then I have added voro++ src path to "include directories". However, this error occured:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall voro::voronoicell_base::voronoicell_base(void)" (??0voronoicell_base@voro@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall voro::voronoicell::voronoicell(void)" (??0voronoicell@voro@@QAE@XZ)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is a link error, seems you forgot to add addition library director + library dependency

Comment: unfortunately, there is no .lib file coming with voro++. I do not know which library files needed.

Answer (score 0):

This library is distributes as source code and uses make file based build system. You need to compile it first into static library. Note that it does not support Visual Studio out of box so to build it you'll probably need to set up your own VS project and deal with all the porting issues that may arise.

Comment: VS 2017 supports cmake out of the box so that might be an option.

Comment: `make` and `cmake` are not the same thing.

Comment: Which is why I said "might be an option". Should be easier to create a workable project with cmake than trying to recreate all the options in the make file via csprojs.

Comment: Creating project probably would be the least difficult step here. Porting from Linux / Cygwin (which it targets by default) is what usually the real problem. Though this particular library does not seem to depend on linux / posix stuff much, except for (seemingly optional) perl scripts.

Comment: Absolutely, I was just throwing out the option since I'd say many people would consider porting a make based system to cmake much easier than having to deal with VS's GUI. But this is rather off topic.